# Firebase security rules on members of document

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, rule-engine

I am using firebase and I'm a bit confused concerning security rules.

Consider the following data structure :

```
{
  viewable:boolean,
  prop1: ...;
  map : { viewable: boolean ... }
}
```

As you see my structure can contains properties with a nested `viewable` property. I want to be able to make queries where objects with the property viewable == true returns the object with the viewable properties, but nested objects with a viewable == false are omitted from the returned results.

At the moment, I tried some security rules but objects with "viewable == false" are still in the result.

And then I saw in the documentation that firebase rules can't be used to filter nested field...

I can't use Cloud Functions either because then I won't be able to observe firestore database changes (with the snapshotChanges API).

Do you know if it is possible to achieve?

Regards

Comment: Can you share what is the query you are making and explain what security rule are you trying to implement? `where("map.viewable", "==", true)` will return all documents where that value is true. Also share any code for reference.

Comment: _"I tried some security rules but objects with "viewable == false" are still in the result."_ Can you share your code so we can see what query are you running? Adding `where("map.viewable", "==", true)` should do it as mentioned earlier .

Comment: `where("map.viewable", "==", true)` will still return results where the root "viewable" property is false, which is undesirable.
In my use case, I want a way to still be able to read `prop1` even if map.viewable is false, since it's not a member of that field - they are unrelated, so simply doing a "viewable == true && map.viewable == true" would also prevent me from achieving this.
Also all these suggestions are still client side, with no way to enforce it, it presents a security risk.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent access to nested fields in a document based on a `viewable` property in those nested fields.